# Displaying text on hover when using column-count

Tags: html, css

Using a font, I create some diagrams. When hovering over a diagram, text is displayed below the diagram. This works as expected. Now I want to create a page with a number of diagrams displayed in two columns and I do this through `column-count: 2;` in the style sheet. However, now the hovering does not work for all diagrams. For example, if I create 4 diagrams and display them plainly below each other the hovering works for each individual diagram, but setting the column count to 2 will make the hovering only work on the two left diagrams.

CSS code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: diagramfont;
src: url("diagramfont.ttf");
}

body {
column-count: 2; /* Removing this instruction and hovering works on all diagrams */
}

.wrapper {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.diagram {
font-family: diagramfont;
font-size: x-large;
}

.overlay {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
text-align: center;
}

.wrapper:hover .overlay {
display: block;
}
```

xhtml:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="diagram">
  Text for diagram
  </div>
  <span class="overlay">
      Text to overlay
  </span>
</div>
<!-- Sequence of diagrams like recent structure --!>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`</body>` closing tag is commented out. Write it as -

```
<!-- Sequence of diagrams like recent structure -->
</body>
```

Try adding `column-count: 2;` to `.wrapper`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. No positive effect of adding column-count on .wrapper.